# I am using SES library sourced on github https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /path/ses/SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php on line 143

https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses

result of the var_dump is bool(false)

my code goes below. why i am not able to send emails , as the emails are verified and the domain too is verified.

```
require_once( "SimpleEmailService.php" );
require_once( "SimpleEmailServiceMessage.php" );
require_once( "SimpleEmailServiceRequest.php" );

$ses    = new SimpleEmailService('access id', 'secret key');

$m      = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();

$m->addTo('shahfaisal106@hotmail.com');
$m->setFrom('vizzwebsol@gmail.com');
$m->addCC('shahfaisal106@hotmail.com');
$m->addCC(array('shahfaisal106@hotmail.com', 'shahfaisal106@hotmail.com'));
$m->addBCC('shahfaisal106@hotmail.com');
$m->addBCC(array('shahfaisal106@hotmail.com', 'shahfaisal106@hotmail.com'));
$m->addReplyTo('vizzwebsol@gmail.com');
$m->addReplyTo(array('vizzwebsol@gmail.com', 'vizzwebsol@gmail.com'));
$m->setReturnPath('vizzwebsol@gmail.com');
$m->setSubject('Sending Welcome Email Through Amazon!');
$m->setMessageFromString('This is the message body.');
//print_r( $m );exit;
var_dump($ses->sendEmail($m));
//print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```